# JS: Resize div when an iframe was clicked?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an entire `<iframe />` with a `div` as parent. That iframe came from different domain. How do you resize it bigger (add class in my case) the parent div when the iframe was click? and resize it back when a close button of the iframe is clicked?

I preferred if the button from `iframe` does the resize but apparently the div cannot be reached INSIDE the iframe, so I have to do it OUTSIDE the iframe.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and wrote a jquery plugin.
https://github.com/BergenSoft/iframeActivationListener

See example:
http://jsfiddle.net/56g7uLub/3/

How to use:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('iframe').iframeActivationListener();
    $('iframe').on("activate", function(ev) {
        $(ev.target).addClass("big");
    });
});
```

This plugin don't use overlaying divs.
It checks if the mouse is on an inactive iframe and starts watching the activeElement of the document.
When it changes to another iframe, the custom event "activate" will be raised.

This is the best solution I found out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("myIFrame").onclick = function(){    
    document.getElementById("myDiv").className = ""; //New Class Name
};
```

---

## Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create some kind of overlay to detect the initial focus event of the iframe. The close button can also be part of your website still if you show it based on class.

http://jsfiddle.net/cxtgn72g/4/

HTML

```
<div id="iframe">
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    <div id="close">X</div>
    <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/6PRq7CmiWhM?list=PLIOa6mDiSeismsV_7YFti-5XOGRzmofSZ"></iframe>
</div>
```

JS - Requires jQuery

```
$("#overlay").click(function() {
    $("#iframe").addClass("big");
});

$("#close").click(function() {
    $("#iframe").removeClass("big");        
});
```

CSS

```
#iframe {
    width : 500px;
    height : 300px;
    position : relative;
}

#iframe.big {
    width : 600px;
    height : 400px;
}

iframe {
    width : 100%;
    height : 100%;
    border : none;
}

#overlay {    
    position : absolute;
    left : 0;
    top : 0;
    width : 100%;
    height : 100%;
}

#close {
    display : none;
}

.big #close {
    cursor : pointer;
    display : block;
    position : absolute;
    right : 10px;
    top : 10px;
    content : "X";
    background : red;
    color : white;
    border-radius : 25%;
    padding : 8px;
}

.big #overlay {
    display : none;
}
```

Comment: Don't need jquery (in fact,must not). I'm developing a chat widget, based on iframe, so I have to assume client don't have jquery. I can just use js `className` for it. As for the close button, it CANNOT be outside the iframe too.

Comment: so basically you are creating a chat plug in for people to inject into their websites. its not your website that needs the plugin?

Comment: yes, and it's done already, thanks for your help (I had a github repo for this btw, just for testing)